# Dealing with contents of an Array

Tags: php

I have an comma seperated list of values held as a string:

```
blue, left-right-middle, panther.png
```

I then have three functions:

1. Sets background colour
2. Sets order of columns for layout
3. Sets a profile image

At the moment I use a `for each` loop to explode the values into seperate strings, but how can I better control the results.

E.g

```
First result of array = Sets background colour
    Second result of array = Sets order of columns
    Third results of array = profile image
```

Can I write the results of the array to 3 seperate variables in anyway, so I can assign the variable to each function?

Like so:

```
    First result of array = $backgroundColour
    Second result of array = $orderColumns
    Third results of array = $profileImage
```

Any ideas how I might go about this?

Comment: Do you *really* hate indexing *that* much?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
$line = 'blue, left-right-middle, panther.png';
list( $bkgColor, $columnOrder, $profileImage ) = explode( ', ', $line );

echo 'Background color: ' . $bkgColor . "<br />\n";
echo 'Column order: ' . $columnOrder. "<br />\n";
echo 'Profile image: ' . $profileImage . "<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP5.3 You could use [`str_getcsv()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse a CSV string into an array.
Also, have a look at [`list`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign variables as if they were an array.

```
list( $color, $order, $image ) = str_getcsv($csvString);
```

Prior to PHP5.3, you'd use `explode` instead of `str_getcsv`. See example by @poke below.

The advantage of `str_getcsv` over `explode` is that you can specify *delimiter*, *enclosure* and *escape* character to give you more control over the result.

`str_getcsv` is smart enough to trim whitespace automatically. The listed values would contain

```
string(4) "blue", string(17) "left-right-middle", string(11) "panther.png"`
```

However, added control does cost speed. `explode` is substantially (~6 to 8 times on my machine) faster for the given example string.

Comment: But when you have the string exactly as formatted above (with `', '` as delimiter), `str_getcsv` won't work, because the delimiter is required to be only one character (and in this example, you also need neither enclosure nor escape, as the possible values of those string is quite restricted).

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
$string = 'blue, left-right-middle, panther.png';
list($backgroundColour, $orderColumns, $profileImage) = explode(', ', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode(', ', 'blue, left-right-middle, panther.png');
list($color, $position, $image) = $array;
echo $color; // blue
echo $position; //left-right-middle
echo $image; //panther.png
```

Answer (score 0):

May you use the str_getcsv function of php.

See in manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code.

$string = 'blue, left-right-middle, panther.png';

list($color, $position, $image) = split (', ',$string);

echo 'Background color: ' . $color ."
\n";

echo 'Column order: ' . $postion. "
\n";

echo 'Profile image: ' . $image . "
\n"

Answer (score -1):

Just to be different, you could use [sscanf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

```
$string = 'blue, left-right-middle, panther.png';

sscanf( $string, '%s, %s, %s', $backgroundColour, $orderColumns, $profileImage );
```