# Array to named variables

Tags: php

How can I take: `$userarray`  (which is an array and I know holds 3 values) and put them into 3 seperate variables instead of looping through. There seperated by `, (commas)` so explode will be in there somewhere.

Say `$userfield1, $userfield2, $userfield3?`

Comment: How's that question different to what you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316998/dealing-with-contents-of-an-array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for either the list() or extract() functionality:

list()

```
list($userfield1, $userfield2, $userfield3) = $userarray;
```

http://php.net/list

extract()

```
extract($userarray); // uses the array keys for variable names
```

http://php.net/extract

Comment: You can also define a prefix for each variable, like `extract($userarray,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'userfield')`. Then all variables would be named `$userfield_1` up to `$userfield_n`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [extract](http://php.net/extract) method.

From the docs:

```
<?php

$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);

echo "$color, $size, $shape";

?>
```

The above example will output:

*blue, large, sphere*

Or do you want to glue your elements together? Then try [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Will print:

*"lastname, email, phone"*

Answer (score 0):

```
extract($userarray, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'userfield');
```

This will create $userfield_1, $userfield_2, $userfield_3 variables (note the underscores).